# How to read a value from 'x'th row and 'y'th column in CSV using Java?

Tags: java, csv

Is it possible to read a specific value from CSV specifed the row number and column number .

For example, my CSV data looks like below,

```
CREATE,BulkDevice4981,SENSOR,localhost
CREATE,BulkDevice4081,SENSOR,localhost
```

I want to read value from row "1" and column "2" without pharsing through the entire CSV.

I need help this regard. Please help me

Comment: if you use `opencsv.CSVReader`, you can set a starting line. then you can call `readNext()` which returns an array of strings. now you can access the element you want pretty easily

Comment: make a count on each readNext(), when your expected number reached then split the line by , and use how ever you want it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can read nth row without looping through previous rows, but it doesn't imply reading whole file.

So, to achieve your goal you need to read nth line of file:

```
try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("path/to/your/file"))) {
    String line = lines.skip(LINE_NUMBER).findFirst().get();
}
```

Then, you can simply split the line by comma and read value from columns:

```
String line = ...
String[] columns = line.split(",")
// columns[2] should contain your value
```

This is however rather primitive solution and it would be better to use dedicated CSV reader like [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Yes, I used opencsv. Below is the code,
`String csvFile = "path_to_file";
CSVReader cr = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
  
  String [] csvCell ;
  
  while((csvCell = cr.readNext()) != null) {
   
   String device1 = csvCell[1];
   
   System.out.println(device1);`
where it returns all the value of column 1.
I want to print row "1" column "2" cell value and row "2" column "2" value seperately.